# the usage of buildWhen in bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to understand bloc statement solution. But i don't understand what is `buildWhen` really used for what. when the value will be true it will return the first statement if if condition. so What does `buildWhen` used for?

**the example is:**

```
BlocBuilder<OrdersBloc, OrdersState>(
  buildWhen: (context, state) {
    return state is OrdersState.OrderCompleted
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is OrdersState.OrderCompleted) {
      return Container(child: Text('Order Completed!'));
    } else if (OrdersState.OrderInProgress) {
      return Container(child: Text('In Progress'));
    } else if (OrdersState.OrderRequested) {
      return Container(child: Text('A customer placed an order!'));
    } else {
      return Container(child: Text('Waiting for an order'));
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: do you get your answer?

Comment: no actually. @JahidulIslam

Comment: Read carefully bold section of my answer?

Comment: actually, the blod section is what i knew, i don NOT knew why to use `buildWhen` ,  yet @JahidulIslam

Comment: Actually buildwhen use for checking builder state every time.

Answer (score 2):

For fine-grained control over when the builder function is called an optional buildWhen can be provided. buildWhen takes the previous bloc state and current bloc state and returns a boolean. **If buildWhen returns true, builder will be called with state and the widget will rebuild.If buildWhen returns false, builder will not be called with state and no rebuild will occur.**

```
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  buildWhen: (previousState, state) {
    // return true/false to determine whether or not
    // to rebuild the widget with state
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)
```

**For** [more about to know follow the link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)